# I converted a website to VB2012 from 2012 Now I get this error Server tag not well formed

Tags: visual-studio, report-viewer2010

I have been trying to reopen the source, rebind the source with no avail.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>

        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"
            SelectMethod="FindAll" TypeName="REPORT SYNTAX" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="match" Type="Object" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
<rsweb:reportviewer width="1200" id="ReportViewer" runat="server" font-names="Verdana".
            font-size="8pt" interactivedeviceinfos="(Collection)"
            waitmessagefont-names="Verdana" waitmessagefont-size="14pt">
            <localreport reportpath=".\Reports\REPORT SYNTAX.rdlc">
                <%--<DataSources>
                    <rsweb:ReportDataSource Name="DummyDataSource" DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1"></rsweb:ReportDataSource>
                </DataSources>--%>
            </localreport>
        </rsweb:reportviewer>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with report-view2010. Is that intentional? Does --%> have a matching opening? Can you post up more of the code?

Comment: You have a full-stop after `font-names="Verdana".` in the `reweb:reportviewer` element. Is that the case?